# How to change all attributes double quotes to single quotes?

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to replace all attributes double quote to single quote. Cause it populate inside a browser I can't parse

> data-pf_settings

attributes value. 
Here is example code of mine.

```
<div class="pf_element" data-pf_title="Header" data-pf_settings="[{"header":"header1"}]" >Hello</div>
```

Want to replace like this

```
<div class='pf_element' data-pf_title='Header' data-pf_settings='[{"header":"header1"}]' >Hello</div>
```

What will be the regex string replace method for this operation?

Comment: why cannot do it manually ?

Comment: Cause browser change all attributes single quotes to double quotes.

Comment: but why you will like to do that? Use some linting tool

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following regex to find:

```
/data-pf_settings\s*=\s*"(\[{"\w+":"\w+"}\])"/g
```

replace it with

```
data_pf_settings='$1'
```

Examine it live at **regexr.com** [here](https://regexr.com/43ol5)

Comment: Thanks a lot @Ahmad. But when data-pf_settings="[{"header":"header1"},{"footer":"footer1"}]"

Then it have to change with data-pf_settings\s*=\s*"(\[({"\w+":"\w+"}|,)*\])"
Got the point thanks again.

Comment: @JakirHossen I assumed you only had one key/value pair. But I am sure you can fix your code to accommodate multiple key/value pairs. If this solved your case, please accept my answer. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

This may help.

`data-pf_settings\s*=\s*"(\[.*\])"/g`

$1 will return the array of all the objects.

Comment: This will mess up the internal JSON format and will not be as the OP wanted

Comment: As per the question, he wants a replace method not parsing technique.

Comment: Your code will output `data-pf_settings='[{'header':'header1'}]'` which will result in invalid HTML format. The OP wants `data-pf_settings='[{"header":"header1"}]'`

Comment: @Ahmad I didn't give him the solution but the way. Surely it will mess up the way you are looking at but may not another way.